# Correct usage of __declspec(dllimport)

Tags: c++, dll, dllimport

I want to build 2 dlls, lets call them `Foo` and `Bar`. I want `Bar` to import some class from `Foo`.

Foo.h:

```
#ifdef EXPORT
#define DECL __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define DECL __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

class DECL Foo {
public:
        Foo();
        void bar();
};
```

Bar.cpp:

```
#include "bar.h"
void bar(){
        Foo f;
        f.bar();
}
```

To build Foo.dll, I do

```
g++ -DEXPORT -c Foo.cpp -o Foo.o
g++ -shared Foo.o -o Foo.dll
```

This produces the following references in Foo.o:

```
$ nm Foo.o
00000000 b .bss
00000000 d .data
00000000 i .drectve
00000000 t .text
0000000c T __ZN3Foo3barEv
00000006 T __ZN3FooC1Ev
00000000 T __ZN3FooC2Ev
```

Now, when I want to build Bar.dll, I do

```
$ g++ -shared Bar.cpp -o Bar.dll
/tmp/ccr8F57C.o:Bar.cpp:(.text+0xd): undefined reference to `__imp___ZN3FooC1Ev'
/tmp/ccr8F57C.o:Bar.cpp:(.text+0x1a): undefined reference to `__imp___ZN3Foo3barEv'
```

If I try to build Foo.cpp with EXPORT not defined (so that the macro DECL evaluates to __declspec(dllimport), I get the following:

```
$ g++ -c Foo.cpp
Foo.cpp:3: warning: function 'Foo::Foo()' is defined after prior declaration as dllimport: attribute ignored
Foo.cpp: In constructor `Foo::Foo()':
Foo.cpp:3: warning: function 'Foo::Foo()' is defined after prior declaration as dllimport: attribute ignored
Foo.cpp: In member function `void Foo::bar()':
Foo.cpp:7: warning: function 'void Foo::bar()' is defined after prior declaration as dllimport: attribute ignored
```

which does make sense, since a function declared dllimport can't then be defined.

How am I supposed to reference `Foo` in `Bar`?

Comment: Isn't `__declspec(dllexport)` for MSVC++?

Comment: @SethCarnegie I'm using MinGW

Comment: Ah, didn't know MinGW supported that.

Answer (score 3):

When you build `Bar.dll` you also need to link against `Foo.lib` with `-l` option

Comment: @javagrendel.. This has more info http://www.transmissionzero.co.uk/computing/building-dlls-with-mingw/

Comment: Technically, since the OP is using the gcc, `Foo.lib` is called `libFoo.dll.a`. Same thing, but different file format for a different compiler.